# wrong data between hc-06 bluetooth module and android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, character-encoding, android-bluetooth, arduino-esp8266

I am working with an esp8266 NodeMCU 1.0 connected to a hc-06 Bluetooth module. I am trying to send JSON Objects by Bluetooth communication.

The problem is that for some reason the information that send doesn't arrive like it should.

I am using two [softwareSerials](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) at the same time

- GPIO2 GPIO0 with 19200 baudRate
- GPIO14 GPIO12with 9600 baudRate

[image]

This is how I am sending the information, I am using [ArduinoJson](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson).

```
StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
  root["act"] = GET_WIFI_STATE;
  root["ws"] = getWifiState();
  root["ssid"] = WiFi.SSID();
  root.printTo(Serial);
  BT.write(' ');
  root.printTo(BT);
  BT.write('\n');
```

In the Android part I am receiving that with a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

```
public void run() {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(mmInStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (inputStreamReader) ;
        while (true) {
            try {
                String pureText = br.readLine();
                String c = new String(pureText.getBytes(),"US-ASCII");
                actionHandler(c);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException", e.getCause() + "");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am sending:

```
{"act":"GS","ws":3,"ssid":"CASTANO JARA"}
```

This is how it's received:

```
{"act":"GS�,"ws":3,"ssid":"CASTANO JARA"}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You might get better responses to this question on [electronics.se].

Comment: thanks. you are right is more an electrical thing than a code problem

Answer (score 1):

I changed the baud rate in the hc 06 module from 9200 to 19200. that fixed the problem